# Show content in Umbraco only after a form is completed

Tags: umbraco

How could I set up a page in Umbraco to only show some particular content (a video in this case) once the user has filled in a form?
We want to add a form to gather user details and only show the content once the form is posted.
Ideally a cookie would be set to store the fact that the form had been completed.

Comment: what version of umbraco are you targetting?

Comment: As you said already, set a cookie when the visitor submit the form and on the page you are showing the video check if the cookie exists otherwise redirect to the page where the visitor has to fill in the details.

Comment: @DacreDenny Using version 7.12.3

Comment: You could also use an AjaxForm that will show the content once it hits success

Answer (score 1):

Use the Members functionality. See https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/getting-started/data/members/ and https://24days.in/umbraco-cms/2015/extending-membership/ for implementation details. Than you can use the out of the box functionality instead of a custom cookie. after filling in the form, login the user, and check IsLoggedIn to show particular content.

To prevent the media accessible via a link without recognized as a member you can use the so called protected media.
see https://our.umbraco.com/packages/website-utilities/media-protect/ or https://codeshare.co.uk/blog/how-to-protect-media-items-in-umbraco/

Another option to protect the media is store the media/video on Azure and generate a SAS token after the form is filled in but this is more for downloading. looks like your question is more about personalization instead of protection. Another option is to use the personalization package, Personalisation Groups from Andy Butland https://github.com/AndyButland/UmbracoPersonalisationGroups